# Powershell complains when not using absolute path

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been trying to make this work for about an hour now and I don't know what I have done wrong. I am trying to launch an .exe from a script and if I use the absolute path C:\xyz\abc.exe, it will launch and PowerShell does not complain. I want to set the same path though for multiple programs I will be adding to that directory, so I am trying to use one variable that points to the path I want which is a folder in the root directory named "Binary" and each executable is inside it's subfolder. So the actual path for the executable would be C:'rootdirectory'\Ketarin\Ketarin.exe. This is what I currently have.

```
$BinaryPath="$PSScriptRoot\Binaries"
$proc = Start-Process "$BinaryPath\Ketarin\Ketarin.exe" -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Here's the complaint:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Ketarin.ps1:19 char:9
+ $proc = Start-Process "$BinaryPath\Ketarin\Ketarin.exe" -NoNewWindow  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\Ketarin.ps1:20 char:1
+ $proc.WaitForExit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Take off the quotes and see if it makes a difference

Comment: No I still get the path complaint.

Comment: $psscriptroot = C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\ in your script. Are sure this is where the "Binaries" folder is?

Comment: Yes when I change to this it works fine.$BinaryPath="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Binaries" it just won't accept the $PSScriptRoot as root directory

Comment: Try this: `$($BinaryPath)\Ketarin\Ketarin.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$BinaryPath=Join-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath Binaries
$proc = Start-Process "$BinaryPath\Ketarin\Ketarin.exe" -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Yes that works! But why does it work? I have never used join-path or split-path. Thank you though!

Comment: Great, glad to help. Your ps1 is in "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Powershell Scripts\Windows Builder Project\Scripts\" but your .exe "\Windows Builder Project\Binaries\Ketarin". With Split-Path you're removing the 'Scripts' folder and then joining it with Binaries.

Comment: wow that was driving me crazy I was googling and googling and couldn't find the answer. Thanks again!